# what will happen if we pass an argument to a C++ recursive function like "pass_by_keyword" in python?

Tags: python, c++

```cpp
int dfs(int idx, int mv, char gest){
    if (idx > n || mv > k){
        return 0;
    }
    int tmp1 = 0;
    if(mv<k){
        if(fj[idx]=='H'){
            if(gest!='P'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, gest='P');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, gest='P');
            }
        }
        else if(fj[idx]=='P'){
            if(gest!='S'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, 'S');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, 'S');
            }
        }
        else if(fj[idx]=='S'){
            if(gest!='H'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1,'H');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, 'H');
            }
        }
    }
    int tmp2 = 0;
    if (check(fj[idx], gest)){
        tmp2 = 1 + dfs(idx + 1, mv, gest);
    }
    else{
        tmp2 = dfs(idx + 1, mv, gest);
    }
    return max(tmp1, tmp2);
}
```

In order to complete an OI problem, I wrote the previous dfs function, but lines 9 and 12 led to incorrect results. If I delete the "gest=" in front of the parameter, the result is correct. Why? What problems will such function parameter transfer bring in C++?

```cpp
if(mv<k){
        if(fj[idx]=='H'){
            if(gest!='P'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, 'P');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, 'P');
            }
        }
        else if(fj[idx]=='P'){
            if(gest!='S'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, 'S');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, 'S');
            }
        }
        else if(fj[idx]=='S'){
            if(gest!='H'){
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1,'H');
            }
            else{
                tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1, mv, 'H');
            }
        }
    }
```

this is right.

Comment: What is your actual question? You're asking what your code will do here, but you could (and probably did) run it simply.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support named parameters. What you are doing is equivalent to this:

```cpp
gest='P';
tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, gest);
```

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you cannot specify the names of the parameters to use a value for when calling a function the way it's possible in python.

```
dfs(idx+1,mv+1, gest='P')
```

will overwrite the value of the `gest` parameter with `'P'` and then evaluate to the new value, so after this expression `gest` has a different value.

I.e. the following 2 snippets have the same effect:

```
tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, gest='P');
```

```
gest = 'P';
tmp1=1+dfs(idx+1,mv+1, gest);
```